# _TypeError type Listdynamic is not a subtype of type List<double>

Tags: flutter, dart

Its been a week since I started with dart, I'm trying to plot the chart which accepts the List double as input data.
I' fetching data from the api and putting the fetched array in the list which i declared.
List aqis;  //list declaration
aqis = mapResponse['aqi_predictions']; //storing the api values

I'm getting this error

```
convert List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<double>

any possible way to convert this list<dynamic> to list<double>
```

Comment: i have tried this but the same error persisit doubleList = aqis.map((s) => s as double).toList();

Answer (score 1):

Here we go!

This solution works for more complex dynamic values in the list like `[1.1, '3', 3, '4.4']` to a `double` `List`

```
void main() {
  List<dynamic> d = [1.1, '3', 3, '4.4'];
  print('Dynamic list: ' + d.toString());
  List<double> dList = [];
  for(var v in d){
    String s = v.toString();
    dList.add(double.parse(s));
  }
  print('Double list: ' + dList.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
Dynamic list: [1.1, 3, 3, 4.4]
Double list: [1.1, 3, 3, 4.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `list` of dynamic to `double` by *iterating* all the elements and `typecasting` them to double.

This following code worked fine for me,

```java
    List<dynamic> x = [2.2, 3.4, 5, 10.2];
    List<double> y = [];
    x.forEach((element) {
      y.add(element.toDouble());
    });
```

If the input list is dynamic like [1.1, '3', 3, 4] having different types then use:

```java
    List<dynamic> x = [2.2, 3.4, "5", 10.2];
    List<double> y = [];
  x.forEach((element) {
      y.add(double.parse(element.toString()));
    });
```

Comment: this is not the correct answer for a dynamic list like `[1.1, '3', 3, 4]`

Comment: if you want to convert string into double then you have to parse the elements,
For this kind of list use this snippet
x.forEach((element) {
      y.add(double.parse(element.toString()));
    });

Comment: yea i know. thats why i said it in the comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have

```
List<dynamic> dynamicList = [1.0,2.0,3.0];
```

And if you tried to assign it to double, it would be:

```
List<double> castedList = dynamicList.cast<double>();
```

Or

```
List<double> castedList = dynamicList.map((element)=>element).cast<double>().toList();
```

For impure List where you have to parse double from string:

```
 List<double> castedList = dynamicList.map((element)=>double.parse(element.toString())).toList();
```

Comment: Your `List<double> castedList = dynamicList.cast<double>();` method not gonna work if the list is more complex like `[1, 2.2, '3.3']`

Comment: Now the last one does.

Comment: But you have to specify in your answer right?